# If someone hacks my wifi connection what if any control do they have over radio waves in my house?

Tags: network, privacy, wifi, wireless

A couple questions on wifi security.

If someone knows my wifi password (be it WEP or WPA) what kind of control do they have over radio waves?  Can they emit radio waves from computers on my network? What about household appliances?

What kind of access would they have to a X Box 1 camera?  Would there be anyway for the hacker to use it if the XBox was completely disconnected?

I guess what I'm really trying to figure out is can/could a hacker transmit radio waves that are audible, but just barely to a person?

Comment: This is kind of an odd question. Can you give us some background?

Comment: Audible radio waves!?!? Not unless you're Superman or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked several different implausible scenarios here. Knowing the access password to your wifi network does not give anyone control over the hardware transmitting the wifi signals.

Even if someone did then also gain access to your wifi access point via the login page, there is nothing on the device that gives anyone control over how the signal is transmitted. It's a little like asking if someone can control your microwave's radio emitter if they have access to the "+30 seconds" button.

As for getting other computers to emit radio waves, access to the XBox camera, or emitting sound: no.

Comment: Unless the OP is asking about something like [Van Eck Phreaking](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104304/can-one-steal-data-using-electric-wire/104389#104389) this is a reasonable and sane answer to a pretty irrational question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's address the quite varied questions individually:

> If someone knows my wifi password (be it WEP or WPA) what kind of
>   control do they have over radio waves?

Next to none. If you've not secured your router, they might be able to change the channel that your Wifi uses, but you need some fairly interesting equipment to do anything outside of the standard wifi spec.

> Can they emit radio waves from computers on my network? What about
>   household appliances?

Simply put, no. They have access to your devices the same as they would if they plugged a network cable in. Unless they have some undocumented vulnerabilities, that fairly severely limits what they can do.

> What kind of access would they have to a X Box 1 camera?

As far as I know, the Xbox 1 is not vulnerable to any attacks either from the network side, or man-in-the-middle. So, none.

> Would there be anyway for the hacker to use it if the XBox was
>   completely disconnected?

No. If there's no power, and no connection, there's no threat.

> I guess what I'm really trying to figure out is can/could a hacker
>   transmit radio waves that are audible, but just barely to a person?

No. Radio waves are not, and will not be audible. They move different things to sound waves.

Comment: Slightly offtopic: I heard a case where someone had an dental implant, and was able to hear music through it. But this guy lived less than 500m from a very strong radio transmitter...